# How can we achieve list like behavior by using pseudo element

Tags: html, css, html-lists, pseudo-element

As we have very few type of List decorator support in html. like circle, decimal disc etc.
If we want to have our custom list decorator then we have to go for pseudo elements. 
ex

```
 (a). Hi list item
 (b). hi there
```

Problems with pseudo elements is that when your pseudo elements 's counter value reach to next digit then content are not aligned properly.
Ex. For numbers counter upto 9 content are align but when 10 comes then list item content shift towards right. Similarly for 100, 1000 ...

To solve this problem I am using display inline-block with text-alignment.

```
  width: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
```

Another problem is that when list-item content overflow to next line then next line start from the same position from where the pseudo element counter is starting.

To solve this i have to use text-indent in em. but that also not a foolproof solution. When both counter value and list item text increases then there is slight misalignment observed.

I have couple of questions here.

- 1. To align pseudo element properly display-inline block is the only option?
- 2. How can we achieve list like behavior by using pseudo selector.
- 3. What all the other possible css styles can we use to align content like list.

Please let me know if i need to put some code snippet or image snapshot of misalignment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have this solution, using `table`. So you don't need to use margins or paddings. Also for styling li as `( x ) .` use it in `li:before content`

```css
ul {
    counter-reset: list;
    width:20%;
    display: table;
}
ul > li {
    list-style: none;
     display: table-row;
}
ul > li:before {
    content: "( "counter(list, lower-alpha) " ). ";
    counter-increment: list;
    display: table-cell; 
    text-align: right;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some more text</li>
    <li>some further text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some more text</li>
    <li>some further text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some more text</li>
    <li>some further text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some more text</li>
    <li>some further text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some more text</li>
    <li>some further text</li>
    <li>some more text</li>
    <li>some further text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some more text</li>
    <li>some further text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some more text</li>
    <li>some further text</li>
    <li>some more text</li>
    <li>some further text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some more text</li>
    <li>some further text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some more text</li>
    <li>some further text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: absolute` for the counter values with `text-align: right` and some `width` value according to the counter value.

Also you will need to provide some `padding-left` to the `<li>` element to align the counter value.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: list;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(list);
  counter-increment: list;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at sapien risus. Ut eget congue est.</li>
</ul>
```